# Got a SIGABRT while building cross-compiler

Tags: linux, compiling, cross-compilation, mono

While building a cross compiler for s390 on x86-32 bit, I got an error :

```
** (/usr/lib/mono/1.0/mcs.exe:23883): CRITICAL **: _wapi_shm_file_open: shared file [/net/lockbox/homes/wxy/.wapi/shared_data-qlnx068-Linux-i686-312-11-0] is not big enough! (found 0, need 1277960 bytes)

** (/usr/lib/mono/1.0/mcs.exe:23883): CRITICAL **: _wapi_shm_attach: shared file [/net/lockbox/homes/wxy/.wapi/shared_data-qlnx068-Linux-i686-312-11-0] open error

** ERROR **: file shared.c: line 312 (_wapi_shm_semaphores_init): assertion failed: (tmp_shared                                                                                                                                               != NULL)
aborting...
```

Any workaround or suggestion?

Comment: What were you building? I can see you were building it with Mono.

Comment: So what is the size and permissions of the said file?

Comment: permission on .wapi folder is drwxr-xr-x and its empty